# How do I compare the values of 3 values in a row, determine the max and then replace all three values with binary numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where we one-hot-encoded 3 columns and then generated synthetic data with adasyn. The values that are returned in those columns are not always 0's and 1's. Instead we have floating numbers. What I want to do is convert those back to binaries. To do this I need to compare all 3 columns in a row, determine the max, convert that to a '1' and the other two to '0'. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [0.9,0.3,0.3 ],
                   "col2": [0.1,0.1,0.2 ],
                   "col3": [0,  0.6,0.5]})

def to_onehot(x):
    oh = np.zeros(x.shape)
    oh[np.argmax(x)] = 1
    return oh

df = df.apply(lambda x: to_onehot(x))
df = df.astype(int)
print(df)
```

The result:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     0     0
1     0     0     1
2     0     1     0
```

EDIT:
To turn col1 to col3 to one-hot encoding:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [0.9,0.3,0.3,0.3 ],
                   "col2": [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.4 ],
                   "col3": [0,  0.6,0.5,0.3],
                   "col4": [2.3,2.1,0.2,0.1]})

def to_onehot(x):
    oh = x.copy()
    oh[["col1", "col2", "col3"]] = np.zeros(3,)
    # x[["col1", "col2", "col3"]].argmax() return the column name
    oh[x[["col1", "col2", "col3"]].argmax()] = 1
    return oh

df = df.apply(lambda row: to_onehot(row), 1)
print(df)
```

The result:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.0   0.0   0.0   2.3
1   0.0   0.0   1.0   2.1
2   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.2
3   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.1
```

Comment: This looks promising but not quite correct. What needs to happen is I am comparing the values in a single row from col1, col2, col3, finding the max and replacing it with a '1' and the others with a '0'. These columns are represent 3 of the 10+ columns and I need to isolate them. Does that make sense?

Comment: Still not quite right. Look at col1[2], col2[2] and col3[2]. The max there is col3[2] not col2[1]

Comment: Something like this returns the max value for the row of three columns but I don't want to create that 'ColMax' column. I just want to replace the max with a '1' and the rest with '0'. df['ColMax'] = df[['Col1','Col2','Col3']].max(axis=1)

Comment: Still playing with this. I know the answer has to be easy but I'm missing it.

Comment: I found that using `df[["col1", "col2", "col3"]].apply` would lead to strange result, so this time I just use `df.apply` and deal with the specific columns in the function.

Comment: Hmmm. Still haven't solved this problem. It still one hot encodes based on the  columns values and not rows.